# Why there is no warning when I try to return a reference of local variable in Clion?

Tags: c++, clion

I have the following code.

Clion generates a warning on function 'getPtr', but no warning on 'getRef'.(Of course, my g++ gives me warnings for both)

I use g++ 7.2 in Clion to compile my code, and I also have Clang 4 on my computer (maybe Clion uses Clang for code inspection?)

```
int &getRef()
{
    int x = 0;
    return x;
}

int *getPtr()
{
    int x = 0;
    return &x;
}
```

Comment: There is no requirement that you get a warning at all.

Comment: i dont know clion, though the tag says "CLion is a cross-platform IDE for C and C++ development." ... what is the compiler then? What flags are you using?

Comment: You probably need to set the compiler flags to a higher warning level.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing those warnings depends on your compiler flags.

For example, you could change your CLion generated CMakeLists.txt to enable more or all warnings.

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")`

Maybe there is a better way to do it directly from the GUI.

Comment: Note that even with more warnings (which you should absolutely enable) there's no *guarantee* you will always get a warning for this. Compilers are not required to be able to detect (nor warn) when you break the language rules (nor can they always do so). It's ultimately the programmers responsibility to *not* engage in undefined behaviour.